# Constraint-based layout of images in a list in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, image, layout, swiftui

I want to achieve the following constraint-based layout of images in a `SwiftUI` `List`:

- pin left/right edges of each `Image` to the list margins (adapts to screen size)
- dynamic height based on aspect ratio (I'd also be ok with fixed height)
- maintain image aspect ratio, and content should fill the space

[image]

What I have tried and doesn't work (based on [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/resizing-images-to-fit-the-screen-using-geometryreader)):

```
struct MyView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
  let aspectRatio = CGSize(width: 345, height: 120)

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
        GeometryReader { geo in
          Image("test_image")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width)
            .clipped()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The size I get from `geo` is (343, 32) on iPhone 11 Pro. Width makes sense but it's not letting the cells expand beyond a height of 32 for some reason. Any tips welcome because I'm really starting to miss auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `GeometryReader` for something like this. For the fixed height, you can just supply a `frame` with `height` only. You also don't need to create your own `let aspectRatio = CGSize(width: 345, height: 120)` - if you leave it nil (by default) it should be fine.

Edit: Using `padding` instead of `VStack` with spacing

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { item in
                Image("test_image")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) /// no need for custom aspect ratio
                    .frame(height: 120) /// fixed height of image
                    .clipped() /// stop image from overflowing
                    .padding(.vertical, 12) /// extra vertical padding
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (with ["test_image"](https://github.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/blob/master/test_image.png)):

[image: Rows of images with fixed height, image stretches to fit container while keeping the aspect ratio]

---

However, this has a fixed height of `120`, so the top and bottom of the images are cropped out. To fix this, you can just avoid `frame` and `clipped` altogether.

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { item in
                Image("test_image")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) /// doesn't matter if it's fit or fill
                    .padding(.vertical, 12) /// extra vertical padding
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Rows of images with dynamic height, image determines the height of the container while keeping the aspect ratio]

Comment: Why do you have VStack _and_ List? Shouldn't it be either or? Thank you though, this got me on the right track. Doesn't answer the dynamic height question but that would be a bonus at this point.

Comment: @rmp251 you are right, it should either be `List` or `VStack` + `ScrollView`. I only did VStack for the spacing - I'll update my answer.

Comment: this solution seems to break when the image is very wide, relative to the fixed height. It does not allow the width to be constrained by the margins. However it works fine for "tall" images (e.g. square).